# How to add videos to subprocess infinitively

Tags: python, path, vlc, popen

I know the title is not very clear. But I could not find a way to express my problem properly. Let me explain: The code below can play videos from a directory perfectly. However, my problem is, The videos in the directory has names like this : 0.avi , 1.avi , 2.avi and so on... As you see in the code, the n value(which represents the video names) is increasing and the "videofilesi" is increasing too. I need to write this code infinitely if I cannot find a solution. Can somebody help me?

```
import definingName
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import os
import random
import sys
import subprocess
import os.path
import glob
import vlc
from subprocess import Popen
n=0
c = 'c'
name = definingName.defName(c)
name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), str(name))

videofilesi = os.path.join('file:///C:/Users/gulbe/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/Lib',name,str(n)+".avi")
videofilesi2 = os.path.join('file:///C:/Users/gulbe/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/Lib',name,str(n+1)+".avi")
videofilesi3 = os.path.join('file:///C:/Users/gulbe/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/Lib',name,str(n+2)+".avi")
videofilesi4 = os.path.join('file:///C:/Users/gulbe/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/Lib',name,str(n+3)+".avi")
videofilesi5 = os.path.join('file:///C:/Users/gulbe/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/Lib',name,str(n+4)+".avi")
p = Popen(["C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe", videofilesi,videofilesi2,videofilesi3,videofilesi4,videofilesi5])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a list.

```
base = 'file:///C:/Users/gulbe/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/Lib'
files = [os.path.join(base, name, f"{n}.avi") for n in range(10)]
p = Popen(["C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe"] + files)
```

Comment: Thank you it is really what I was looking for. However, I cannot write huge numbers inside the range. Is it a way to write 10000 inside the range for example?

Comment: Do you mean you can't call `vlc` with a large number of arguments? I think you want a playlist, which would allow `vlc` to read the list of files to play from a file, rather than its command line arguments. I'm not sure how that works from the command line, though. (Unless you just use `["C:/.../vlc.exe", "my_playlist.txt"]`, after creating `my_playlist.txt` appropriately.)

Comment: This code plays videos from a directory when videos are recorded. So, creating a playlist is not working (I tried) Only this kind of approach (giving number of every file etc) solved my problem. I mean in your example code you wrote " for n in range(10)" but if I wanted to write there 10000 instead of 10, The program does not work because the number is too big. Can I solve this in some way?

Comment: `range(10000)` works just fine. The problem is that you (apparently) are limited in how big an argument list `Popen` can use to call `vlc`. That's an operation-system limit you can't work around, which is why I suggested finding someway *other* than command-line arguments to specify which files `vlc` should open.

Comment: In short there is a python file which records videos that are 5 seconds long to a directory, and there is another python file which plays these videos from the directory in real time.

Comment: I see. What can I use instead of popen?

Comment: `Popen` isn't the problem either; if you went to the console and tried to type `vlc.exe 1.avi 2.avi ... 10000.avi`, you would have the same problem. You simply can't invoke a command with 10000 arguments (or rather, with some number of arguments whose combined size exceeds a certain OS-specific limit).